# Custom Validation Replacers in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5.1

I am trying to create a custom validation replacer in my Laravel 5.1 application.

I currently have

```
Validator::replacer('year', 'App\CustomValidators@replaceYear');
```

in my `AppServiceProvider` file with the corresponding living in my custom class. However when I include `:year` in a validation message, it is not replaced. what am I missing?

Here's my replacer function.

```
public function replaceYear($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters)
{
    return str_replace([':year'], $parameters, $message);
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What I really should have done was set up my replacer similar to this:

```
Validator::replacer('dateInYear', 'App\CustomValidators@replaceDateInYear');
```

the `dateInYear` name corresponds with the name of the custom validation rule that I set up. What I ultimately ended up doing, though, was extending the validator class so I no longer have to declare every single custom rule and replacer. My validator class now looks something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use \Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

class CustomValidator extends Validator
{

    /**
     * The new validation rule I want to apply to a field. In this instance,
     * I want to check if a submitted date is within a specific year
     */
    protected function validateDateInYear($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator)
    {
        $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $value)->startOfDay();

        if ($date->year == $parameters[0]) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    //Custom Replacers
    /**
     * The replacer that goes with my specific custom validator. They
     * should be named the same with a different prefix word so laravel
     * knows they should be run together.
     */
    protected function replaceDateInYear($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters)
    {
        //All custom placeholders that live in the message for
        //this rule should live in the first parameter of str_replace
        return str_replace([':year'], $parameters, $message);
    }
}
```

This lets me leave my AppServiceProvider file alone for the most part, only needing registering the new validation class, which I really could do in any service provider.

Laravel's documentation is exceptionally lacking on what needs to happen for replacers, so I hope this helps someone down the road.

Comment: What's the purpose of inheriting from Laravel's Validator, here? You don't seem to access any internal protected methods or member variables, so it's kind of superfluous. Other than that ... you're right on track! Have an upvote :D

Comment: Thanks, your comment helped me out! I got an error however, which was solved in another issue. It stated that you shouldn't extend the Validator in your custom class, as this breaks things.

Comment: This answer got me on the right track. I called the replacer inside the validation function, like this: `$validator->addReplacer('dateInYear', 'App\Services\CustomValidator@replaceDateInYear');`

Comment: this doesnt seem to still work in laravel 8.x as you cannot just easily register a validator any longer (uses factory now)